# react.js TypeError: lights.map is not a function

Tags: reactjs, axios

So i am trying to map the data i get from this api, but it gives an error saying "TypeError: lights.map is not a function"
Here is the function which is called to make the call from the API:

```
    function getLight(){
    Axios.get('http://{IP}/api/{KEY}/lights').then((res) =>{
        console.log(res.data)
        setLights(res.data)
        })
}
```

And here is my map:

```
<button onClick={getLight}>Lights 1</button>
        <div> 
            {lights.map((light) =>{
                return(
                 <li>{light.name}</li>
                )
                 })}
        </div>
```

Comment: Hello! Maps only work in array, check if `res.data` is an array

Comment: What is the type of `lights`? Is it an object, an array, a string...?

Comment: Sorry my mistake forgot to show this too, but i have defined it like this
const [lights, setLights] = useState([]);

Comment: Ya sure, you have initialized `lights` with `[]` but when `lights` will be updated, it may take any value which can be objects, strings, etc. So, you should check what is the `datatype` of `res.data`. If it is 'array', then only you can `map` over it or you have to somehow convert it into array.

Answer (score 1):

You should be sure that lights will always be an array so you can use map function.

If you are not sure that lights will be an array you can use

```
<>
{lights?.map && lights.map((something)=><div>{something}</div>)}
</>
```

Or, if you do not have access to modern syntax

```
<>
{lights && lights.map && lights.map((something)=><div>{something}</div>)}
</>
```

So you will check if map function really exists in lights object(or it's prototype) prior to using it and if not - return undefined and React will not render that line of jsx (you can render some kind of loader animation while you not have an array, for example)

**BUT** I don't think it's good solution - you really need to check when your variable gets non-array value which cause an error.